# Move from UITableView to a UIView on Table Cell press

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I'm trying to move from a UITableView to a UIView from clicking a table cell.
I'm using a Manual Segue which is hooked up to the UITableView's View Controller and then hooked to the UIView's View Controller with a given name.

I'm using this to call it:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"todoEditSegue" sender:self];
```

But I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<TodosViewController: 0x6e47230>) has no segue with identifier 'todoEditSegue''
```

The Segue is definately there, I'm using a storyboard.

Any ideas how I can get this working asap?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the concerned `Segue` in `Storyboard` on the right side go to the `Storyboard Segue` add `todoEditSegue` in identifier

Comment: Done that same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

If you programatically made the table via importing it and instantiating it, then the segue no longer exists, instead instantiate it using:

```
UITableView *myTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoard.Identifier"];
```

and then on your storyboard click the tableView in question and open the right panel, go to the custom class tab (3rd tab) and put a storyboard ID in the box and tick the box "use storyboard ID"

make sure the storyboard ID you put in is the same as the string "StoryBoard.Identifier"